# Is whooshalchemy indexing changing back reference?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, whoosh

I am using flask and whooshalchemy to implement full text search in a simple web application. The Post and User models are defined like this:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['body']
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   body = db.Column(db.Text)
   author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)
```

In some view I perform a check whether current user is allowed to edit the post

```
post = Post.query.get(pid)
if current_user != post.author:
    abort(403)
```

For some reason `current_user` and `post.author` are not the same object if `whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Post)` is called. If I comment out that line then the test for the ownership of the post works as expected.

Why is this happening? Does whooshalchemy indexing create a copy of `post.author` that is different from what is loaded from `user` table? What can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

The official whooshalchemy has a bug - Miguel covered it [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling). Use his fixed version [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/commit/1e17350ea600e247c0094cfa4ae7145f08f4c4a3) and that should solve your problem.